# Setting the 'secure' and 'httponly' flags globally for php/apache

Tags: php, apache, cookies

The website works on HTTPS completely, there are no pages on HTTP. I would like to set the secure and httponly flags for the cookies. 
Instead of doing so for every cookie, is there any way to do it globally, for all cookies? 
As mentioned in the title, I use PHP 5.3 and Apache.

Note that, I know it is possible for Session Cookie, but I need it for all cookies in the website.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.

The only way you can manage this is to have a helper function:

```
function setSecureCookie($name, $val = '', $exp = 0, $path = '', $domain = '') {
    return setcookie($name, $val, $exp, $path, $domain, true, true);
}
```

Comment: Too bad :( I'll have to work harder. OK, thank you very much.